# Remi repository alternative for Ubuntu

Tags: php

In Centos/REHEL/Fedora, it is possible to have separate installations of PHP using Remi repositories.

The main version (e.g. 5.6) is installed in /usr/bin and the Remi version (e.g. 7.1) is installed in /opt/remi/phpXX/root/. The new version is totally independent and the /opt directory has a directory structure similar to linux itself.

We can then have two different PHP-FPMs and use them for different websites as needed.

Is there a similar thing for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use the Ondrej repo.  It's more up to date than the default 18.04 Ubuntu repo.  However, it is unfortunately lagging a bit behind Remi.  I wish Remi was available on Debian/Ubuntu, but alas.

https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/